# Do I need to accept an answer on a feature-request question?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

I [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89039/bug-on-question-list-on-account-page) what I considered to be a bug, and was advised to make it a feature request.

Do I need to accept the answer? I'm not sure of etiquette on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's not strictly necessary, but I'd accept an answer if it actually gets implemented.